# If I do PPL ground school online, do I have to do all of it?

Tags: flight-training, ppl, transport-canada

I am not doing normal ground school (I chose to do it online). I have passed my [PSTAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSTAR), and will be doing my ROC-A in the upcoming weeks.

With this in mind, must I do the entire online ground school course? I do not know if my instructor (or worse, the FAA) will check if I have finished all of the online work.

Comment: There's an easy way to find out what your instructor will do: ask him/her.

Comment: Forgive me, but are you sure that your attitude and flying are compatible?

Comment: Just a brief reminder to everyone: Voting a question up or down is a comment on how good/bad the question is, not how good/bad the attitude of the questioner themselves is.  This question is actually a very important one, and it's written well.  I'm not sure why anyone is voting it down.

Answer (score 3):

You need at least 40 hours of ground school, according to the [Transport Canada regulations (421.26)](http://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/regserv/cars/part4-standards-421-1086.htm#421_26). So you will need some sort of evidence to show that you have done so.

I do hope that you weren't seriously considering doing this. Please read the answers to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/198/how-dangerous-is-flying-in-a-single-engine-plane).

You will see a common theme - most accidents are caused by the pilots themselves. Knowing aviation theory inside and out is the best protection you have against joining them in those statistics. It is not a stretch to say that your life depends on the attitude you bring to your flight - starting from the first lesson of ground school.